# The natural domain of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{5−x^2}}{(x−1)(2x−1)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

**Background**

As there is a radical in the numerator, this restriction would need to be applied first.

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{5−x^2}}{(x−1)(2x−1)}$$

Thus, $x=-\sqrt{5}$, and for the denominator, $x=1, x=\frac{1}{2}$

The natural domain would then be: $[-\sqrt{5},\frac{1}{2})∪(\frac{1}{2},1)∪(1,\sqrt{5}]$

Am I on the right path here? Also, am I correct in saying this natural domain ends at $\sqrt{5}$, rather than $∞$?

Comment: That's correct. Basically your conditions are: $5-x^2 \geq 0 \, \wedge x \neq 1 \, \wedge x \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but your explanation could be clearer.

You didn't say what "$x = -\sqrt{5}$" means, and what about $+\sqrt{5}$? I would say that from the radical, we know $5 - x^2 \geq 0$, so $x^2 \leq 5$, so $-\sqrt{5} \leq x \leq 5$.

Similarly for the values where the denominator would be zero: I would either use words like "the denominator cannot be zero, which would happen at $x = 1$, $x = \frac 12$", or just write $x \neq 1, x \neq \frac 12$ to match the actual conclusion.

For a way to double check whether the natural domain stops at $\sqrt{5}$ or extends to $+\infty$, imagine plugging in some really large positive number for $x$. If $x$ is large and positive, then $5-x^2$ is large and negative, and $\sqrt{5-x^2}$ is a problem. So very large positive numbers should not be in the domain.

Comment: That's great, thanks for that. I have a follow up question, regarding $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{5−x^2}}{(x−3)(5x−2)}$ I used a calculator and as the denominator cannot be zero, which would happen at $x=3$, $x=\frac{2}{5}$, the solution is $[-\sqrt{5},\frac{2}{5})∪(\frac{2}{5},\sqrt{5}]$. In this case, why would $x=3$ not be included in the solution?

Comment: But then $5-x^2\lt 0$